# ASP.NET controls in Eval if else statement?

Tags: asp.net, eval

I want to show checkbox or radiobutton according to typeId.

```
<%# (Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1") ? "CheckBox" : "RadioButton"%>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' />
```

If typeId == 1 I want to show checkbox that is in my code line else I want to show radio button.
How can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the visible property of both controls.

Comment: This is too difficult for me. Because I used 3 nested repeater and this code in third level repeater :)

Comment: Why does that make it difficult?

Comment: beceuse of more codes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Visible` property:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' 
    Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1" %>'
/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' 
    Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() != "1" %>'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two bool properties to your datasource called, for example, ShowCheckBox and ShowRadioButton

```
public bool ShowCheckBox
{
    get
    {
         return TypeId.ToString() == "1";
    }
}
```

and use these to data bind to the Visible properties

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("ShowCheckBox")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1") ? True : False %>" Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' />
```

Comment: This is good idea. but occur "string too bool not converted error". I solved it with Tim Schmelter's answer

Answer (score 0):

In the Repeater.ItemDatabound event, add the appropriate control there.